# Does every vector space contain a zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

If this is true, then every vector space must always have at least one subspace, the one consisting of only the zero vector, correct?

Thanks!

Comment: By the definition of a vector space, yes.

Comment: The existence of a zero vector is in fact *part of the definition* of what a vector space is: this makes your question quite weird.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, and yes, you are correct.

The existence of a zero vector is in fact part of the definition of what a vector space is.

Every vector space, and hence, every subspace of a vector space, contains  the zero vector (by definition), and every subspace therefore has at least one subspace:

The subspace containing only the zero vector *vacuously* satisfies all the properties required of a subspace. It is closed under vector addition (with itself), and it is closed under scalar multiplication: any scalar times the zero vector is the zero vector.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't it one of the requirements for a vector space to have a zero vector?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's my first yes. My second yes is that the zero vector constitutes a subspace of every vector space.

Answer (score 6):

Every vector space also contains itself, and is its own subspace.

Except in one very special situation (which one?) it follows from this that almost every vector space has *two* subspaces.

Comment: I was going to add that observation... +1 for posting it!

Comment: what is the 'special' situation?

Comment: @JohnathonSvenkat, you tell me :-) Which are the only vector space which have one *one* subspace?

Comment: the vector space spanned by the zero vector?